# Conversation of legacy jsf project to angular

Tags: angular, jsf, migration

I am looking for guidance to go ahead with migrating my legacy myfaces project to angular.
Project has 2k simple to complex pages. I am thinking to do phase conversion and don't want to convert all pages in one go. I don't know if angular can go together with jsf. I read about frame but if anyone has any examples please let me know.

I hope someone must have been through this situation before. It will be great help if you provide me pointers to do jsf to angular conversion.

Thanks!!

I am checking on different forums but no luck yet.

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries for quick response.  I have already read these threads. If you check the discussion, They are in opinion to create new angular projects altogether. Can i use same jsf project and add angular pages into it? So tht over the period of one year i have all jsf pages in angular? Does jsf coexist with angular? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Nobody has said it's impossible.

Comment: Hi @BalusC..can you please help me some links or details which I can refer to get understanding?